# Disable drag & drop custom control onto windows form designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouseevent

I have a C# application which supports run time for design like visual studio

I want to limit the designer window for some controls only. windows forms designer window cannot accept other controls. I want to change mouse pointer as unavailable when it holds user control on mouse over the designer form.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: I want to change mouse pointer as unavailable when it holds user control on mouse over the designer form.

Comment: This is very confusing? Are you talking about run time cursor change? and how this is relates with drag&drop?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes am talking about run time cursor change. I have a C# application which supports run time for design like visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem....

If you are implementing controls, override the [MouseHover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of each control that you need to change the mouse pointer.

e.g.

```
protected override void OnMouseHover(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.No;//particular region is invalid for the current operation.
}
```

You can find different Cursors on [Cursors Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)